# HTML Form Not Submitting to MYSQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have been trying to get this to work for some hours. I have researched many threads on here trying to see if I could find the problem with my code. I am new to PHP and I keep getting a Internal Server error, but I cant seem to track it down. I have tried all sorts of methods suggested online to get this to work with no luck. Its a basic user signup form in HTML, in a PHP file.(I was going to do both html and php on the same file but could not get that to work) The idea is to have the form submit to my MYSQL database to a customer table. If any of you could shed some light on what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<form id="signupField" action="register.php" method="post">
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="FN" size="auto"/><br>
Last Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="LN" size="auto"/><br>
Street Address:<br>
<input type="text" name="SA" size="auto"/><br>
City:<br>
<input type="text" name="City" size="auto"/><br>
State:<br>
<input type="text" name="ST" size="auto"/><br>
Zip:<br>
<input type="text" name="Zip" size="auto"/><br>
Email Address:<br>
<input type="text" name="Email" size="auto"/><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="text" name="Password" size="auto"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Referenced PHP:

```
<?php 
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "serviceaccount";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "nameofdb";
$conn = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
<?php

$FName=$_POST["FN"];
$LName=$_POST["LN"];
$SA=$_POST["SA"];
$City=$_POST["City"];
$State=$_POST["ST"];
$Zip=$_POST["Zip"];
$Email=$_POST["Email"];
$Password=$_POST["Password"];

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO Customers(FName,LName,StreetAddress,City,State,Zip,Email,Password) VALUES('$_POST["FN"]','$_POST["LN"]','$_POST["SA"]','$_POST["City"]','$_POST["ST"]','$_POST["Zip"]','$_POST["Email"]','$_POST["Password"]')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');</script>";
} else {
echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."');</script>";
}

$conn->close();
}
}
?>
```

**EDIT** After finding this error: Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (0) I was able to solve the connection issue to the database. Now when I put in the rest of the PHP back in I get a 500 Error still. It definitely narrows down where the issue is though!

**EDIT** I want to thank you all for you help on here. The main issue was the SQL connection. After I got that taken care of, I found that I had an extra bracket in place which was the cause for the other internal error I was receiving.

Comment: Check apache error_log file file for detail. also the way you are putting data in database is so dangerous.

Comment: You're insert query is probably causing you issues, plus you're assigning your POST values to variables, yet in your query, you don't use the variables and insert the $_POST data. That also leaves you very vulnerable to SQL injection, use the mysqli prepare syntax https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the "basic check" question: the html with the form and register.php are in the same directory, right? Not includes, requires, etc

If you have access to the apache error_log, check it out first to see the error message you're getting. If you can't understand it, post it here to help you.

If you don't have acccess to the file, first we need to find where are you getting the mistake. As an idea, start with this in register.php...

```
<?php 
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "serviceaccount";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "nameofdb";
$conn = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

Got to http://[yourdirectory]/register.php  DIRECTLY and see what you get. Then start adding the rest step by step and let us know when you get the mistake.

Other think to check is the database NULL variables configuration. All the columns allow null values? Are you filling all form fields or are you leaving any field empty?

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes the html and php file are in the same directory. I do not have access to any of the log files unfortunately. When I use just the connection statement i get this: Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (0). Im guessing that means it cant even find the host server? Also the table does not accept any null values.

Comment: Yes. Attending at the response, it seems that you can access to the Mysql server. First check this:

1. The mysql server is up and running.
2. It uses the 3306 port (maybe is configured to use a different port).
3. Your user $username has permissions to access the database $dbname.

Check this first and let me know the results

Answer (score 0):

Replace your register.php code with following.

```
<?php 
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "serviceaccount";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "nameofdb";
$conn = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

if it prints that connection failed; then you have to check your code for connecting to database.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It does seem to be a connection issue. I am still tracking down where it went wrong. The error message it displayed was: Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (0)

Answer (score 0):

Use isset($_POST["FN"]) .. etc for all post variables and  try to use variables $FName , $LName etc. in your insert query instead of direct $_POST variables. 
e.g.

```
$FName = '';
if(isset($_POST["FN"]) && $_POST["FN"] !=''){
    $FName = $_POST["FN"];
}
```

Also check whether connection is opening or failing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Upon further inspection one of the big problems I am having is with my connection. If I leave just my connection information on the PHP the page will return: Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (0).

Comment: @Heathen0042: Are you using correct credentials to make connection with database. Please try to use Sql Yog Community edition or HeidiSQL, Or Phpmyadmin tool to check whether its connecting to database.

Answer (score 0):

before insert any new field into your db use

> mysql_real_escape_string

check for empty params before insert these to db

use the following to turn all error reporting on for MySQLi

> mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

Comment: Thank you, I added the mysql_real_escape_string to my code, but it still gave me the error. Where will i see the error reporting for MYSQLi?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your variables that you assigned for your post fields instead of the $_POST-objects and make sure you sanitize all user inputs.

You could try replacing your $sql-string with the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Customers(FName,LName,StreetAddress,City,State,Zip,Email,Password) VALUES('$FName','$LName','$SA','$City','$State','$Zip','$Email','$Password')";
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I tried it, but it still does not seem to solve my problem. Upon further inspection it looks like it has to do with my connection. They return this error: Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:3306' (0)